# JavaFX Alert Dialog and java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: alert, javafx-8

I try to display an Alert Dialog in JavaFX.

This is the source :

```
   Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
               alert.setTitle("Confirmation dialog");
               alert.setContentText("remove ?");

               ButtonType btOk = new ButtonType("Yes");
               ButtonType btCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel",  ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE); 

               alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(btOk, btCancel);                       
               Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
               ...
          } 
    });
```

When i execute this source, i have this error message :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassStage.windowsSetEnabled(GlassStage.java:166)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setVisible(WindowStage.java:470)
  at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:857)
  at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
  at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
  at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:910)
  at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:925)
  at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
....
```

Any ideas ?

For information i use this version of the JDK : 8u60 ea-b13

Thank you in advance,

Fabrice

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @IBACK: excuse me the last version of JDK that is released by oracle is: Java SE 8u45, so how have you got 8u60????

Comment: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: it will not possible to provide a SSCCE (it's too complicated) - JavaFX Alert Dialog is not supported by this verison of JDK - so i find an other solution. thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @IBACk, I have the same problem, find a solution ?, I hope you can help me Thanks

Comment: sorry I don't find a solution, so i use a workaround.